# Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#

**how to remove the error when i withdraw an amount**

```
 con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\anaabenoja\Documents\sample connection.accdb";
 sql = "SELECT * FROM Acc_info where  account_no = " +txtaccno.Text;     
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.CommandText = sql;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(Log_in);
        if (Log_in.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
error -->  *balance = (string  )(Log_in.Rows[0]["balance"]);*
            num1 = int.Parse("balance");
            num2 = int.Parse(txtamount.Text);
```

Comment: You can't **cast** a numeric value to a string. Call `.ToString()` on it instead (assuming you need it to be a string!)

Comment: Since it's a boxed `int`, cast to `int` or `int?` instead of to string. You can call `ToString()` if you *really* want a string.

Comment: @AntP yo! I do agree...but, we don't know what datatype is there in database

Comment: @AntP I assume that it's a boxed integer. I don't know if it's guaranteed to be non null.

Comment: @AntP it could be an `int?` if the column is nullable.

Comment: @crashmstr But it itsn't an `int?` - the error message says so.

Comment: @AntP There is no such thing as a boxed `int?`. `int?` boxes to either `int` or `null`. For this particular row you could unbox to `int`. But I don't know if other rows a null, so I suggested both casting to `int` or `int?`, leaving it to the OP to choose which applies here.

Comment: @CodesInChaos my last comment was not a reply to you. Your previous comment was edited following my reply.

Comment: @AntP hello sir im using ms access and the fdatatype of my balance is shortttext should i convert it into number ?

Comment: @MarlonEdAguillon it sounds to me like `balance` should not be a `string` in the first place.

Comment: @AntP what should i do sir ? and i also try to use [.tostring] and came another that said that "Input string was not in a correct format.' on the num1 = int.parse("balance ")

Comment: @MarlonEdAguillon That's a whole separate issue. `"balance"` cannot be parsed to an integer. `balance` can. However, I am still wondering why `balance` is a string in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 con.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\anaabenoja\Documents\sample connection.accdb";
 sql = "SELECT * FROM Acc_info where  account_no = " +txtaccno.Text;     
 cmd.Connection = con;
 cmd.CommandText = sql;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        da.Fill(Log_in);
        if (Log_in.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
error -->  *balance = (string  )(Log_in.Rows[0]["balance"]);*
            num1 = int.Parse("balance");
            num2 = int.Parse(txtamount.Text);
```

Do you even need to cast to string if you are parsing it a line later??!

Just use:

```
num1 = Log_in.Rows[0]["balance"]
```

Not sure what `DataAdapter` does as I don't use it much but worst case cast the value to int if it's not already int (i.e. it's boxed - obviously don't cast to int if it's a non compatible type!):

```
num1 = (int)Log_in.Rows[0]["balance"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace 
`balance = (string  )(Log_in.Rows[0]["balance"]);`

with

`balance = Log_in.Rows[0]["balance"].ToString();`

This will have the effect of insuring that whatever value is present there is returned in a string format.  If you must also handle null values, try
[Convert.ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.